# Architecture Internals of Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am newbie to Fink and wondering if there is any documentation on the latest description of Flink internals. I came across this (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Flink+Internals) and not sure if this is the latest as many updates were in 2015.

Thanks in advance.

-Rao

Comment: There are several sources of additional information about the internals -- such as the docs, blog posts, Flink Forward talks, training materials, FLIPs, and the book by Hueske and Kalavri. Is there some topic you are specifically interested in?

Comment: try to show us what you have tried, please show some effort before asking to avoid down voting